# OpenZeppelin Ownable not behaving under Hardhat? (Previously thought to relate to client vs. EVM address cAsing.)

Tags: addresses, hardhat, testing, openzeppelin

EDIT: I original thought this was an address cAse comparison issue but comments and further investigation has eliminated that idea.

#### TL;DR:

`TestContract.sol`

```
function blah() public view onlyOwner returns (uint256 anInt) {
  console.log(msg.sender); // => 0x8077ad64fd2cd872f1454a76ae2d8474ccdcf90b
  console.log(Ownable.owner()); // => 0x8077ad64fd2cd872f1454a76ae2d8474ccdcf90b
  return 0
}
```

**Reverts with**: `'Ownable: caller is not the owner'`

`Test.js` `owner.address` vs. EVM `msg.sender` cAsinG

```
msg.sender    => 0x8077ad64fd2cd872f1454a76ae2d8474ccdcf90b
owner.address => 0x8077Ad64Fd2CD872f1454A76AE2D8474cCDcF90B
msg.sender.toLowerCase() === owner.address.toLowerCase() => **TRUE**
```

#### !TL;R>0

Please note that the two addresses have the correct letters and numbers but the EIP-55 mixed case checksum is different (EDIT: apparently **NOT** the issue here.)

Any clues, anyone?

### Additional Context

(edit)

- I'm using `@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol`
- A minimal function is reverting with `'Ownable: caller is not the owner'`
- Example contract function:

```
function returnAnInt(address _address, uint256 index) public view onlyOwner returns (uint256 anInt) {
  console.log(msg.sender); // => 0x8077ad64fd2cd872f1454a76ae2d8474ccdcf90b
  console.log(Ownable.owner()); // => 0x8077ad64fd2cd872f1454a76ae2d8474ccdcf90b
  return 0
}
```

**NOTE** that both `msg.sender` and `owner()` return **identical** strings

- Test.js example ...

```
const [ owner, otherOwner ] = ethers.getSigners();
console.log(owner.address); // => 0x8077Ad64Fd2CD872f1454A76AE2D8474cCDcF90B
await expect(testContract.connect(owner).returnAnInt(otherOwner.address, 0).not.to.be.reverted;
```

=> `AssertionError: Expected transaction NOT to be reverted, but it reverted with reason 'Ownable: caller is not the owner'`

- In hindsight based on the console logs, the address cAse is not the actual problem

Comment: The checksum doesn't exist at the EVM level. So it is up to the tool logging msg.sender if they add the checksum or not.

Comment: I wondered about that but the hardhat (ganache?) EVM is giving me 'Ownable: caller is not the owner' even though the console.logs are as stated above. I'm migrating from Truffle, which did not seem to have this issue ... which in itself makes little sense given the shared code and well, hence my confusion.

Comment: I've added further context to the original post.

Comment: Hardhat uses a modified version of ganache.  It seems to be a bug in their implementation. Did you try running the contracts with the real EVM? or ganache. It is a bit odd that it reverts but the console.logs are printed anyway.

Comment: @Ismael good idea. I'll do that now.

Comment: Good grief. Now I'm getting NO revert reasons, even though I'm using `ganache v7.4.3 (@ganache/cli: 0.5.3, @ganache/core: 0.5.3)` with  `--chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse=true` :/ I'm about ready to ditch Hardhat and return to Truffle.

Comment: Perhaps you have to start with an existing repo like hardhat boilerplate, and learn how it works before migrating a truffle project. I won't say that one is better than the other, every tool has its pros and cons. There are other alternatives like foundry, web3py, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your help @Ismael. I've since discovered by debugging at the @openzeppelin/access/ownable.sol level, that under some circumstances msg.owner was different for every call. This led to realizing my test set-up for SOME of the tests was the problem.  Not sure if I should "answer your question" or delete this thread, since it's unlikely to be useful to anyone, being all out of context and all.

Comment: If you have solved the problem then adding an answer might help other users in similiar situations and the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In the end this came down to the previously unmentioned fact ("because it had no relevance" :/) that the contract under test is cloned by a factory contract, using `@openzepplin/contracts/proxy/Clone.sol`.

This means that each function call actually occurs **twice**. The first call has the expected `msg.sender` but the *second* call has `msg.sender` as the contract's *own* address, due to being proxied from the original implementation.

`@openzepplin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol` does not account for this behaviour, making the second (proxied) call revert with, `'Ownable: caller is not the owner'`

My solution was to simply roll my own 'Ownable' (minus transferability which is not required in this instance) ...

```
    modifier onlyContractOwner() {
        require(_owner == msg.sender || address(this) == msg.sender, "Caller is not the owner. Police enroute.");
        _;
    }
```

Noting `|| address(this) == msg.sender`

I could have instead overridden `_checkOwner()` from Ownable.sol but I don't want transferability anyway so this saves a little bytecode size.

What fooled me was that `address(this)` is the *same* for *both* calls, whereas I might have expected implementation contract address for the first call, followed by the cloned contract address for the latter.